# How do I repeat a AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am just wondering how you repeat a AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405959/how-to-do-unlimited-repetition-by-using-avaudioplayer-in-ios

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Set the Property numberOfLoops to -1 and it would go into infinite loop.

Comment: rather do upvote if it really helped you so that it can help other usesr in future...

Comment: upvote suggests that this reply helped you and this might be helpful to other users as well.Hope you got my point:)

Comment: anything for AVPlayer to repeat audio?

Answer (score 14):

Do you mean 'How do I set an `AVAudioPlayer` to repeat a sound?' I assume?

if so:

Notice that AVAudioPlayer class has a property called `numberOfLoops`.  If you set this property
to a negative integer value, when you play the `AVAudioPlayer`, it will loop until stopped.  You can set the number of loops you'd like to play by making `numberOfLoops` a positive integer.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for that, all helps is a big help!

Answer (score 14):

From the iOS docs:

> numberOfLoops
>
> The number of times a sound will return to the beginning, upon
>   reaching the end, to repeat playback.
>
> @property NSInteger numberOfLoops Discussion A value of 0, which is
>   the default, means to play the sound once. Set a positive integer
>   value to specify the number of times to return to the start and play
>   again. For example, specifying a value of 1 results in a total of two
>   plays of the sound. **Set any negative integer value to loop the sound
>   indefinitely until you call the stop method**.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.2 and later. Declared In
>   AVAudioPlayer.h