# Playing music within app

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-audio

I have a soundtrack I would like to play throughout my app even when users change view controllers and such. I have a loop from a soundtrack that I want to repeat once it finishes.  I am currently playing sounds through:

```
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                       pathForResource:@"Click03" ofType:@"wav"];
AVAudioPlayer  *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
               initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundFile]
               error:nil];
[audioPlayer start];
 // or [audioPlayer stop];
```

I am not quite sure if this the best way of playing sounds. Can someone explain to me how to do what I asked above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are trying to play an background audio..

Check the following links this would help you

[Play music in the background using AVAudioplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619794/play-music-in-background-in-iphone-using-avaudioplayer)

http://www.sagorin.org/2011/11/29/ios-playing-audio-in-background-audio/

For repeating audio check this link

[How do I repeat a AVAudioPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804160/how-do-i-repeat-a-avaudioplayer)

Answer (score 0):

Write code to play sound in Appdelegate.

```
-(void)PlaySound:(NSString*)strSoundFileName 
{
    fileURL=[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:strSoundFileName];
    audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    audioPlayer.delegate=self;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    audioPlayer.currentTime=0;
    [audioPlayer play];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops=-1;
}
```