# How to do unlimited repetition by using AVAudioPlayer in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

In my app i am using audio. I want to play audio for unlimited time on tapping button. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to re-play the player when it reaches the end :

```
-(void)startPlayer {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    NSError *error;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    player.delegate = self;
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [aPlayer play];
    }
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)aPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag {

    aPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    [aPlayer play];
}
```

Call `[self startPlayer];` once, and it will loop forever !

Answer (score 5):

`AVAudioPlayer` has a [`numberOfLoops`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/numberOfLoops) method. Set that to -1 for unlimited repetition.